# Display number in original format not in scientific notation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a text file, that when I import into excel looks like this:

[image: Raw Data]

I've been trying to do the following:

Column A is the controller.
When a number above "97" appears in Col A I want to delete it.
I only want to let the first row of "1's" remain.
For every "2" that appears, I firstly want to copy the value in Col B in the "2" row, and paste it over every "3" until I hit the next "2".
Then I'd like to delete the Row's with "2".

So eventually the file should look like:

[image: After Macro]

What I've got so far is:

```
Sub Deleterow97()
'Macro to format text file to readable format for client

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "97" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "98" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "99" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "1" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    Dim CellValue As String
    Dim RowCrnt As Integer
    Dim RowMax As Integer

    With Sheets("Sheet1")   ' Replace Sheet1 by the name of your sheet
        RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For RowCrnt = 1 To RowMax
            If .Cells(RowCrnt, 1) = "2" Then
                .Range("A:A").Replace What:="3", Replacement:=.Cells(RowCrnt, 2), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                  ReplaceFormat:=False
            End If
        Next

        Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = Last To 2 Step -1
            If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "2" Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

When the replace function copies the value in Col B for every "2" in Col A it then pastes over every 3 with a number that looks like: 1.11111110+28

Comment: What isnt working? what is your Question?

Comment: Sorry Tobias, Silly me! 
It all seems to work ok, but when the replace function copies the value in Col B for every "2" in Col A it then pastes over every 3 with a  number that looks like: 1.11111110+28

Comment: Sorry, this may be a very simple fix for someone on here, but I'm totally lost! :( 
Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop so many times as you can use an OR in 1 loop and you don't need those variables for a one off thing really, This doesn't fix your problem but here is a much shorter and easier to manage version of your code:

I put a couple of comments in where I am not sure what it is supposed to do.

```
Sub Deleterow97()
'Macro to format text file to readable format for client
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "A").Value = "97" Or Cells(i, "A").Value = "98" Or Cells(i, "A").Value = "99" Or Cells(i, "A").Value = "1" Then Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
Next i
With Sheets("Sheet1")   ' Replace Sheet1 by the name of your sheet
    For RowCrnt = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If .Cells(RowCrnt, 1) = "2" Then .Range("A:A").Replace What:="3", Replacement:=.Cells(RowCrnt, 2), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'I am not sure why this is in the WITH, should it be .Cells??
        If Cells(i, "A").Value = "2" Then Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete 'See above comment Also don't use brackets around the cells(blahblah) in the If, you don't need them
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dan,

Have made the changes, but still seems the format of Col A is scientific once the macro completes.

Comment: What format should it be? You can set it as you loop through

Comment: It should be just a copy paste of exactly what is in Col B next the the "2" in Col A, until you hit the next "2" in Col A.

Comment: Okay I will take a look tomorrow, I'm not at a machine right now

Comment: Thanks Dan, appreciate it! :)

Comment: Hi Dan,
Any joy finding time to help a VBA novice out!?

Comment: Sorry mate, I am flat out at work at the moment. Hopefully someone else jumps on this and picks it up otherwise I should have some time tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Dan,
Looks like no one else jumped in here. Can you try to resolve please?